Is upgrading with MariaDB 10.5 somehow possible?
So far I have been upgrading my Drupal site from 8 to 9 to 10 successfully.
However I could not upgrade it from 10 to 11 because my shared hosting has MariaDB 10.5, while D11 requires 10.6.
Is it somehow (by overriding or even by hacking the core) possible to make Drupal 11 work on MariaDB 10.5?
In that way, I could go ahead with this upgrade and wait for the hosting to upgrade MariaDB at a later date.

Yes. Linked from the change record about Drupal 11’s database requirements is a module that allows older versions.

This module lets you install and use Drupal 11 on MySQL 5.7.8+ and MariaDB 10.3.7+, which match Drupal 10's requirements. This makes it easier for people to upgrade from Drupal 10 to Drupal 11, even if you don't yet have access to the higher MySQL or MariaDB versions.

